# Browsable Django REST API wrapper for external API calls

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I'm building a RESTful interface to a Django project, and I need to leverage external APIs to allow the client and frontend to reference just the one Django API without needing the details of the external APIs.

Therefore, I want the external API data to be returned to the browsable API pages as I would my own view-based API.

How do I serialize a JSON response from an external API to the browsable API web-page renderer?

For example, I want mysite.fake/thing/details to return the same JSON that is returned by externalapi.fake/thing/details, which looks like:

```
{"thing_id": "900404", "description": "Thing description", "value": "100.00", "location": "Bin 401"}
```

And have that show up in the browsable API for DRF.

Currently, I'm using:

```
@api_view(('GET',))
@renderer_classes((JSONRenderer,))
def thing_finder(request, thing_id):
    """
    Get the current location for a thing
    http://localhost:8000/thing/find/9900404
    :param request: HTTP Request object
    :param thing_id: String - the thing ID
    :return: JSON - The Thing location JSON
    """
    a, b = THING_API_AUTH
    if request.method == 'GET':
        payload = {'thing_id': thing_id}
        r = requests.get(THING_API_AUTH, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(a, b), params=payload)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            data = json.loads(r.text)
            serializer = ThingFinderSerializer(data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response({"error": "Request failed"}, status=r.status_code)
```

In `settings.py` I include:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ]
}
```

This works (I think), but it doesn't format the results to the Browsable API. Instead, I get an unformatted page with the JSON dumped to it. Am I missing a template requirement? Wrong URL in the browser? Is `BrowsableAPIRenderer` in `settings.py` not sufficient to default render to the Browsable API? TIA.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use the serializer here, as the external source returning the JSON data. You can make use of the **`response.json()`** method as

```
@api_view(('GET',))
@renderer_classes((JSONRenderer,))
def thing_finder(request, thing_id):
    a, b = THING_API_AUTH
    if request.method == 'GET':
        payload = {
            'thing_id': thing_id
        }
        response = requests.get(
            THING_API_AUTH,
            auth=HTTPBasicAuth(a, b),
            params=payload
        )
        if response.status_code == 200:
            return Response(response.json(), status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response({"error": "Request failed"}, status=response.status_code)
```

Comment: I'm attempting to get the response to render in the DRF browsable API - if I use your method, I get the same unstyled page with just raw JSON returned. But, this is a good tip for just raw JSON.

Comment: Then what was the format that you are expecting? show some example

Comment: A formatted render like this: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#browsableapirenderer

Comment: I don't understand what is the difference. Probably adding a screenshot or image might help (me) to understand the situation

Comment: I solved it - I needed to include the BrowsableAPIRenderer decorator along with the JSONRenderer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I solved it:

```
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer, BrowsableAPIRendererenter
@api_view(('GET',))
@renderer_classes((JSONRenderer, BrowsableAPIRenderer))
def thing_finder(request, thing_id):
    """
    Get the current location for a thing
    http://localhost:8000/thing/find/9900404
    :param request: HTTP Request object
    :param thing_id: String - the thing ID
    :return: JSON - The Thing location JSON
    """
    a, b = THING_API_AUTH
    if request.method == 'GET':
        payload = {'thing_id': thing_id}
        r = requests.get(THING_API_AUTH, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(a, b), params=payload)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            data = json.loads(r.text)
            serializer = ThingFinderSerializer(data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response({"error": "Request failed"}, status=r.status_code)
```

This returns the Browsable API render in a clean, formatted page.